# Wordpress y SASS

Tags: php, javascript, css, bootstrap, wordpress

Tengo mi tema **Wordpress desarrollado por mi y usando el framework bootstrap** 4( no recuerdo si usé starter theme ).

Ahora **quiero reescribir mi hoja de código de CSS a SASS o SCSS** para tenerlo más organizado y optimizado. He investigado mucho en internet pero no me quedan claras las opciones para poder editar mi tema. ¿Debo descargar mi tema de mi host y editarlo localmente instalando SASS en el proyecto? ¿O debo usar un tema que soporte SASS como underscores.me y empezar de nuevo?

Os gradeciría un poco de luz ya que he visto muchos foros y cada uno lo hace de una forma.

Gracias

Comment: Actualizarlo a Sass? Creo que estás un poco confundido pues el preprocesador Sass compila el código que escribas a css plano que de hecho es el único que puede leer el navegador

Comment: Se que el navegador solo lee CSS, quizas me he explicado mal. Lo que quiero es reescribir mi código en SASS para tenerlo más ordenado y optimizado.

Comment: Con Boostrap 4 puedes utilizar tu propio custom.scss para trabajar variables, mixins y demás. Te comparto info sobre SASS en Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass

Comment: No tengo bootstrap descargado en el proyecto, lo hago con llamadas en el functions como esta, para que asi tenga la version mas reciente de bootstrap: 
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );

Para el estilo tengo un style.css con mis estilos en la raiz del proyecto.